# limit at infinity of $\frac{x-\sin(x)}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I use l'Hospital rule to calculate
$$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{x-\sin(x)}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
?

> Intuitively, it seems like the denominator tends to $\infty$ faster
> than the numerator, so I guess the limit is $0$. But how can I use
> l'Hospital's rule to calculate this formally?

Differentiating the denominator and numerator once yields $\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{1-\cos(x)}{e^x-1-x}$, and the numerator does not even have a limit in this case. Dividing everything by $x$ or $x^2$ doesn't seem to help in anything. Also, using Maclaurin expansion does not help here because we are in a neighborhood of $\infty$.

In addition, how can we prove that  $\lim_{x\to\infty }(e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}) = \infty$ to start with (without using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition )?

Thank you!

Comment: By definition, $$
e^x  - 1 - x - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} = \frac{{x^3 }}{6} + \frac{{x^4 }}{{24}} +  \cdots  > \frac{{x^3 }}{6}.
$$

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^2} = \infty$ by L'Hopital, now use this result , along with product laws to get a proof for the second result. Of course L'Hopital doesn't apply there directly, so you will have to be a little roundabout  regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $\lim_{x\to\infty}1-\cos(x)$ doesn't exist. Nevertheless, and since $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x-1-x=\infty$,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{e^x-1-x}=0,$$and therefore, by L'Hopital's rule, your limit is $0$ too.

Comment: Thanks @Jose Carlos! Can you help me also figure out how to use l'Hospital rule to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (e^x-1-x) = \infty$?

Comment: You will find several answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044337/446262).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I would suggest that you make it explicit that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable near $a$, and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ (or $-\infty$), then we can apply L'Hôpital's rule to a limit of the form $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/g(x)$ (it need not be the case that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$; in fact, this limit might not even exist).

Comment: @JoshuaRectangle: See my above comment. To apply L'Hôpital's rule, it doesn't need to be the case that the numerator tends towards infinity.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative

$$\frac{x-\sin(x)}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\frac{x}{e^x}\frac{1-\frac{\sin(x)}x}{1-\frac 1{e^x}-\frac{x}{e^e}-\frac{x^2}{2e^x}} \to 0\cdot 1=0$$

and we can use squeeze theorem

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}x\right|\le \frac 1 x \to 0$$

and l'Hospital for each term to show that $\frac{x^n}{e^x} \to 0$ or also referring to

- [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/505767)